# Inconsistent capitalization of links in top bar dialogs

Tags: feature-request, hyperlinks, top-bar, capitalization

There are a couple of links in various dialogs in the top bar, and the capitalization isn't consistent; some of them are all lower case, some are sentence cased (the latter is the [new standard](https://stackoverflow.design/content/guidelines/grammar-and-mechanics/#buttons-and-links)). From left to right:

- MOD MESSAGES

  - Mod Team Q&A
  - dashboard
- INBOX

  - all items
- ACHIEVEMENTS

  - privileges
  - badges
- REVIEW QUEUES

  - All queues
  - Tools
- CURRENT COMMUNITY

  - help
  - chat
  - log out
  - edit
  - company blog

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: What would you like to happen?

Comment: Looks like [it's capitalized](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qtqji.png) in the new (upcoming) inbox dialog, so at least this one is scheduled to be fixed. That leaves the elements in the first and third screenshots above.

Comment: [The content guidelines in the Stacks design principles indicate that sentence casing should be used for all headings and calls-to-action.](https://stackoverflow.design/content/guidelines/grammar-and-mechanics/#use-sentence-casing) That said, many of these links were added to the UI before those guidelines were in place, so a bunch of the older parts of the UI just use lowercase for everything. I think these bits have been gradually getting replaced when a change is being made to the relevant UI elements - it's not something that we've tried to fix all at once.